# Angular service promise

Tags: angular

I have created a service fetching data from a server but I cant figure out how to retrieve the resolved data in my controller.

Here is the service:

```
export class UserService {

    getUsers() {
      let data = [];
      return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/users')
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log(response); //Response gets logged
              response.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);  //Data gets logged
                return data;

            })
        };
    ...
```

In the component/controller

```
export Class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.userService.getUsers();
  }
}
```

I guess the problem has to do with me returning the function "fetch" itself instead of the resolved data. But I cant figure out the correct way to go about it.

Comment: You're missing a `return`. It should be `return response.json()`

Comment: Also, you're assigning a promise to `users`. You may not want this so try `this.userService.getUsers().then(users => this.users = users)`

Comment: @Phil maybe he/she want to using `async` pipe in template :)

Comment: @TiepPhan Could be, I'm not up with Angular 2+. Not sure what can be done in the template these days :)

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? The [tag:angularjs] tag is typically for AngularJS 1.x

Comment: Angular 2. Using typescript. The error im getting is that type Promise<void> is not assignable to to type any[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
export class UserService {

    getUsers() {
      return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/users')
        .then(function(response) {
           console.log(response);
           return response.json();
        });
    }
}
```

In your component:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.userService.getUsers();
  }
}
```

And using with `async` pipe in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | async">
  <span>Maybe print username: {{user.name}}</span>
</div>
```

In case you don't wanna using `async` pipe:

The code in your component:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().then(data => {
      // do something with response data
      console.log(data);
      this.users = this.someMethodToTransformResponse(data);
    });
  }
  someMethodToTransformResponse(data) {
    // return modification your data
  }
}
```

and your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  <span>Maybe print username: {{user.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works if I wish to send the data directly to the view ( which is true in this case). I had no idea that i had to use a pipe in the view. But lets say that i wanted to do something with the data inside of my controller first?

Answer (score 1):

We're missing return response json inside then of promise.

```
export class UserService {

    getUsers() {
      let data = [];
      return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/users')
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log(response); //Response gets logged
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);  //Data gets logged
                return data;

            })
        };
    ...
```

getUsers service is Ajax call so put result inside then of it.

```
export Class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().then(users => {
        this.users = users;
    });
  }
}
```